# Better programing style?

Tags: java

Which code is better?
Using return() in every condition:

```
void someProc(String str) {
    if (str.length < 1) {
        log("bad length");
        return();
        }
    if (str.charAt(3) == "N") {
        log("N at 3");
        return();
        }
    parse(str);
}
```

or subconditions without return():

```
void someProc(String str) {
    if (str.length < 1) log("bad length");
    else if (str.charAt(3) == "N") log("N at 3");
    else parse(str);
}
```

What is better for perfornance?

Comment: You really should code `return;`  not `return();`  and your question is a metter of taste and style. No influence on performance with an optimizing compiler.

Comment: -1 for the tagging alone. What language is this?

Comment: Wooble, sry but I thought on such a site users could recognise such a language :)

P.S.: it's java

Comment: @iamnp, it's always better to be clear, since C-style languages like Java often look similar to each other in small code samples.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no meaningful difference in performance.  The compiler should generate basically the same instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This type of question generally attracts strong and violent arguments.

For me, I prefer to use return only when a value is returned because I think that an empty return can be confusing (for example, "did the programmer forget to type the variable name") and I don't mind multiple exit points.  I would write someProc as follows:

```
void someProc(String string)
{
  if (str.length < 1)
  {
    log("bad length");
  }
  else if (str.charAt(3) == "N")
  {
    log("3 is N");
  }
  else
  {
    parse(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Although sometimes it's helpful to actually just return right where you are.  Typically this would happen if you need to skip the rest of the code in the method and there's no nice clean way to do it without adding may levels of nested if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test on your dataset. I cant find any noticeable difference.

I think it would be better if you post this code at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Hope this help!